# Email Alerts to external users - SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, email, alert

I'm having problem sending alerts to external users. The site collection allows external users but when I type in the email adress like gmail it says that the organization do not allow it.

[image]

If it's not allowed what's the easiest method to send alerts to external users when they add, edit items in a list.

Comment: I have the same configuration than you and it works perfectly with hotmail, it must to be be a gmail account?

Comment: It has to send alerts to all kind of domains. The company wants to send alerts to users personal email adr.  I've also tried to send it to a hotmail adr but it seems that I need to "approve" that, but I don't know where I do that. I've searched inside the admin center ..

Comment: @Plexus81 I think you should check your SMTP settings. Maybe your SMTP settings is restricting to send emails to external domains.

Comment: @RohitWaghela are you able to send to ex gmail?

Comment: @Plexus81 I have not implemented Email alerts for external domains. But You can refer this link i found while googling. May be this could help you out to resolve the issue-- http://blog.armgasys.com/?p=164

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Plexus81,

The theory is the following.

1) The invitation must be accepted first [image]

2) When the external user account has accepted the invitation, then it ill be displayed as  #EXT#, in the O365 User administartion console
[image]

3) It might by you need to configure the [O365 SMTP relay](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn554323(v=exchg.150).aspx#configconnector). Only then one can add to the alerts list.

4) The challenge is pass the invitation at least with a O365 trial version. So far I did not find a way to pass the federation step.